# Client Side Caching of XML returned from HTTPHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, ashx, ihttphandler

I have an HTTPHandler that returns some XML.  I am trying to figure out how to get this to cache in the browser, as if it were a static XML file.

I've tried this along with a few other variations and other Cache options, but nothing I do seems to make it cache (according to Fiddler).

Any ideas on how I can cache the output on the client's browser?

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
        context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));

        string sXml = GetTableAsXml();
        context.Response.Write(sXml);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image from HttpHandler won't cache in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994135/image-from-httphandler-wont-cache-in-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994135/image-from-httphandler-wont-cache-in-browser) might help you.

Comment: Perfect, thanks - didn't realize I needed to send the 304 myself.